# How do I unset spl_autoload_register() and from where does it run?

Tags: php, autoloader

When using `spl_autoload_register()`, if I understand correctly, once you run it, PHP saves it for every file.

The question I have, and this is really three questions, is:

1. How do you remove a function from spl_autoload_register()?
2. Does spl_autoload_register() save the functions to be autoloaded and restore them upon restarting php?
3. Does the function in spl_autoload_register() always run from the same location?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [php.net/spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register). On the left side, under `spl_autoload_register`, it says `spl_autoload_unregister`.
2. It saves the autoloders every time the script runs (which is every time someone visits the page).
3. If I understand this question then, yes. If you tell it where to find something then it will always look there (unless you do something iffy).

Comment: If php shuts down, will the autoloader be removed?

Comment: For the third one, I meant, say I autoloaded a function that had includes in it to `/php/php.php` in `index.php` and then I ran a page on `pages/index.php`, would it search `pages/php/php.php` or would it still search the original directory?